# Adjoing $p$th roots to rings: as quotients of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

**Motivation/Setup:** Suppose $R$ is a domain. I'd want to "adjoin $p$th roots of an element $a \in R$." where $p$ is a prime (which i am mostly interested in $p$-adic) This seems to be a cmomon operationo in $p$-adic goemetry. See the rings of interst below.

**Goal:** I would like to express these objects as a quotient of polynomial.

1. Let $K$ be the algebraic closure of fraction field of $R$, and *make a choice of $a^{1/p}$* for $a \ inR$
2. Suppose $a^{1/p} \notin R$.
3. There is a map
   $$ R[x]/(x^{p}-a) \rightarrow R[a^{1/p}] \hookrightarrow K$$
   $$x \mapsto a^{1/p}$$

**Question:** Are there simple criteria to test is if first map is iso? For instance, i'd like to adress the three cases below.  I could explain 1. in example.

**Examples of interest:**

4. $R=\Bbb F_p((t)), a=t$. This is adressed below combining the two observations below in my thoughts. In otherwords, I bellieve I have proven :
   $$F_p((t))[t^{1/p}] \simeq F_p((t))[y]/(y^p-t)$$
5. $R=\Bbb Z_p, a=p$. I would like to adjoint $p$th roots of unit as

$$\Bbb Z_p[\xi_p] \simeq \Bbb Z_p[y]/(y^{p-1}+\cdots +1)$$

7. $R=S[x]$, $a=x$, where $S$ is some domain like $\Bbb Z, \Bbb Z_p, \Bbb Q_p$. I would like to state something as

$$\Bbb Z_p[x][x^{1/p}] \simeq \Bbb Z_p[x][y]/(y^p-x)$$

---

**Thoughts:**

The map is clearly surjectiev. So we are down to the case of innjectivitiy.
Let $I:= \ker(R[t] \rightarrow R[a^{1/p}])$. This is a prime ideal.

*Condition 1: When all prmies of $R[t]$ are principal/$R$ is a field* These are equivalent condition.

*Condition 2: $R$ is of charateristic $p$* The question is equivalent to finding minimal polynomial of $a^{1/p}$ over $R$. Over $K$, $x^p-a=(x- a^{1/p})^p$. Thus, if in $R[t]$, it is reducible, we must have $a^{k/p} \in R$ for some $1 \le k <p$, and $(k,p)=1$ would imply $$(a^{lk/p}a^b)^p=a$$ for some integers $b,l\in \Bbb Z$, this shows we have found a $p$th root.

Comment: That map is not "canonical" because the symbol $a^{1/p}$ is ambiguous: It just means any element whose $p$th power is $a$, of which in principle there could be many. Actually, two such elements have as quotient a $p$th root of unity and conversely, multiplying one with a $p$ root of unity gives another one, so there are $p$ distinct ones in $K$ unless the characteristic of $R$ is $p$.

Comment: The polynomial $x^p - a$ is *monic*, and there is always unique division with remainder by a monic polynomial over an arbitrary commutative ring.  Surely you don't want $a$ to be a $p$th power in $R$.  Is $R$ integrally closed in all cases that interest you? If so, then $f(x) \in R[x]$ has $a^{1/p}$ as a root if and only if $(x^p - a) \mid f(x)$ in $R[x]$.

Comment: As a concrete example, take $R=\mathbb R$ (real numbers), $p=3, a=2$. Now by $2^{1/3}$ we could mean the real number $\approx 1.26$, in which case your second assumption is not satisfied (as this is an element of $R$). But if instead we mean one of the complex solutions $\approx 1.26\cdot(-1/2\pm i\sqrt3/2)$, we have $R[a^{1/p}] = \mathbb C$ but the quotient on the left has $\mathbb R$-dimension 3 (it is $\simeq \mathbb R \times \mathbb C$) and the map is not injective.

Comment: TorstenSchoeneberg thannks I edited my post. KCd, i'm not totally sure I understand you. I'm really just trying to find explicit representations of common constructions in adjoining pth roots. I edite dmy post. Tell me if i'm still unclear.

Comment: Well but even with your edit, my example shows that the answer depends on the choice of $a^{1/p}$ and in some cases is negative. As KCd's comment and reuns' answer suggest, to guarantee a positive answer you want to ensure that *no choice of $a^{1/p}$ lies in $R$*. If, and only if, that is the case, you get a positive answer (which further is independent of that choice.)

Comment: Great, ok these comments and answer clarified a lot of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p$ prime $x^p-a\in K[x]$ is irreducible iff it has no root in $K$.

Let $b$ be a root in the algebraic closure and $f$ its minimal polynomial, of degree $m$.

- In characteristic $p$: $x^p-a=(x-b)^p$ so $f=(x-b)^m, f(0)=(-b)^m\in K$, if $m<p$ then $b\in K$.
- In characteristic not $p$:

  $f=\prod_{j=1}^m (x-\zeta_p^{c_j} b)$ so $f(0)=(-1)^m \zeta_p^r b^m\in K$. If $m<p$ then $\zeta_p^{rs} b\in K$ where $sm=1\bmod p$.

  And hence $x^p-a$ has a root $\zeta_p^{rs} b\in K$.
- Conversely if $x^p-a$ has no root in $K$ then $m=p$ ie. $x^p-a$ is irreducible and for any subring $R\subset K$ containing $a$,  $R[b]\cong R[x]/(x^p-a)$.